# 400 Request audio can be a maximum of 10485760 bytes in speech-to-text-v2 through GCStorage URI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm using the google speech-to-text-v2 API for transcription with the Chirp model.

I'm trying to transcribe an audio file which is longer than 10 minutes. Since there is a restriction of 10MB for local files, I am uploading the file to a storage bucket and trying to transcribe from that bucket.

````
def transcribe_audio(audio, language_code):
    start = time.time()
    # Authenticating clients
    client_options_var = client_options.ClientOptions(
        api_endpoint="us-central1-speech.googleapis.com"
    )
    storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
    speech_client = speech_v2.SpeechClient(client_options=client_options_var, credentials=credentials)

    gcs = GCStorage(storage_client=storage_client)

    # Creating bucket if not present
    bucket_name = 'text-stores'
    if not bucket_name in gcs.list_buckets():
        bucket_gcs = gcs.create_bucket(bucket_name=bucket_name)
    else:
        bucket_gcs = gcs.get_bucket(bucket_name=bucket_name)
    
    # Uploading audio file to audio-files folder
    audio_destination = f'audio-files/{audio}'
    audio_path = f'{os.getcwd()}/{audio}'

    gcs.upload_to_bucket(bucket=bucket_gcs, blob_destination=audio_destination, file_path=audio_path)

    # Transcribing audio file

    transcript=''
    gcs_uri = 'gs://' + bucket_name + '/' + audio_destination

    config = cloud_speech.RecognitionConfig(
        auto_decoding_config=cloud_speech.AutoDetectDecodingConfig(),
        language_codes=[language_code],
        model='chirp',
    )

    request = cloud_speech.RecognizeRequest(
        recognizer="projects/tpus-302411/locations/us-central1/recognizers/my-chirp-recognizer",
        config=config,
        uri=gcs_uri,
    )

    response = speech_client.recognize(request=request)```

ERROR: google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request audio can be a maximum of 10485760 bytes.
````

Comment: The file is too large. Submit smaller files.

Comment: That is why I am using the storage bucket instead of directly reading the file and uploading it from my local machine. The code works perfectly fine if I am using the Google speech-to-text v1 API. It throws this error only with the newer Chirp model

Answer (score 2):

According to [chirp docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/v2/docs/chirp-model#available_api_methods),
we should use `Speech.BatchRecognize` instead of `Speech.Recognize` for file longer than 1 minute.

> Chirp processes speech in much larger chunks than other models do. This means it might not be suitable for true, real-time use. Chirp is available through the following API methods:
>
> - v2 Speech.Recognize (good for short audio < 1 min)
> - v2 Speech.BatchRecognize (good for long audio 1 min to 8 hrs)
>
> Chirp is not available on the following API methods:
>
> - v2 Speech.StreamingRecognize
> - v1 Speech.StreamingRecognize
> - v1 Speech.Recognize
> - v1 Speech.LongRunningRecognize
> - v1p1beta1 Speech.StreamingRecognize
> - v1p1beta1 Speech.Recognize
> - v1p1beta1 Speech.LongRunningRecognize

I've got it working by using the `BatchRecognize` example from [python-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/3bfadd88732e24cd282ca4fc7e0353154e3fe77b/speech/snippets/transcribe_batch_gcs_input_inline_output_v2.py)

```py
file_metadata = cloud_speech.BatchRecognizeFileMetadata(uri=gcs_uri)

request = cloud_speech.BatchRecognizeRequest(
    recognizer=f"projects/{project_id}/locations/global/recognizers/_",
    config=config,
    files=[file_metadata],
    recognition_output_config=cloud_speech.RecognitionOutputConfig(
        inline_response_config=cloud_speech.InlineOutputConfig(),
    ),
)

# Transcribes the audio into text
operation = client.batch_recognize(request=request)

print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
response = operation.result(timeout=120)

for result in response.results[gcs_uri].transcript.results:
    print(f"Transcript: {result.alternatives[0].transcript}")
```